# Using Kotlin's @JvmOverloads with Android's Fragment.newInstance() pattern

Tags: android, kotlin

I've tried to accomplish this by defining the both as top-level fun and as a companion object static fun, but I get the same result. I'm able to see generated methods but there's none for `newInstance(mouse: Mouse?)` What am I misunderstanding about how this gets called from Java?

```
// MyFragment.kt
@JvmOverloads
fun newInstance(bird: Bird? = null, bee: Bee? = null, cat: Int? = -1, mouse: Mouse? = null) : MyFragment {
  //Put params in Bundle, put bundle in fragment...
  return MyFragment()
}

// MyActivity.java
MyFragment fragment = MyFragmentKt.newInstance(bird, bee, cat); // compiles
MyFragment fragment = MyFragmentKt.newInstance(mouse); // does not compile
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/) annotation makes the compiler generate all methods by leaving out the end-parameters. It does not generate methods for all permutations of parameters.

> If a method has *N* parameters and *M* of which have default values, *M* overloads are generated: the first one takes *N-1* parameters (all but the last one that takes a default value), the second takes *N-2* parameters, and so on.

So `MyFragmentKt.newInstance(bird)` will exist, while `MyFragmentKt.newInstance(mouse)` or even `MyFragmentKt.newInstance(bee)` won't exist.

Comment: I see @tynn. Then my options are to manually overload `fun newInstance(mouse: Mouse?)` **or** use it by `MyFragmentKt.newInstance(null, null, null, mouse);`

Comment: I think that's the best options you've got.